# Atualização parcial do objeto / Não atualizar valores nulos com JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Estou utilizando JPA para um webservice, e estou utilizando o `Merge` para atualização, mas ele atualiza todos os valores do meu objeto, há alguma maneira de realizar uma atualização parcial do mesmo ?

Exemplo, só alterar valores que não são nulos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A operação `merge` do JPA sempre vai sincronizar todo o estado do objeto no banco de dados. Porém existe uma forma de realizar o que você pretende:

1. Carregue o objeto original do banco de dados pelo `Id` usando `find()` do session do JPA
2. Use uma biblioteca como `BeanUtils` para copiar as propriedades não nulas do objeto atualizado parcialmente produzido pelo serviço para o objeto carregado pelo `find()`. Veja como fazer [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301697/helper-in-order-to-copy-non-null-properties-from-object-to-another-java)

O JPA vai gerar o update mas apenas as propriedades alteradas no objeto carregado terão valores diferentes.